# How can I negate the %in% operator (or return the complement of two sets)?

Tags: r

I have two lists or similar, and I want to get the items in `big_list` that are *not* in `little_list`.

```
big_list  <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
little_list  <- c(2,4)
big_list[big_list %in% little_list] # this gives me the interection
```

But I want the complement (items in big_list that aren't in little_list, i.e. `big_list\little_list`).

This doesn't work

```
big_list[big_list ! %in% little_list]
```

Neither does this

```
big_list[big_list %in% ! little_list]
```

I am assuming there is an answer I should have worked out by myself?!

Comment: I'm a fan of `Hmisc::"%nin%"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setdiff(big_list, little_list)
 #[1] 1 3 5
```

Or

```
 big_list[!big_list %in% little_list]
 #[1] 1 3 5
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Took my longer to write the question than it did for you to answer, but quicker than trying to figure it out by myself. Now waiting for SO to let me mark this as answered.

Comment: @drstevok I am sure you could have figured it by yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You may create this function in your source file or Rprofile and load it at start.  Pretty convenient.

```
'%!in%' <- function(x,y)!('%in%'(x,y))
```

then you could do

```
big_list[big_list %!in% little_list]
```